# How to pass object data to a window.open()

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to pass JavaScript objects to a window.open() without having the objects in a URL. I know i can do this when loading a url into a div:

```
$("#myDiv").load(urlForWindow, { data: data });
```

But is there a way i can do this for a window:

```
var win = window.open(urlForWindow, '_blank', { data: data });
```

Comment: Once the window is created most browsers will allow parent -> child communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i realized, why make this harder. just use [ajax post to an api.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function openWithData(url, data){
   window.open(url, "page");
   const ping = setInterval(() => {
      window.postMessage(data, "*");
   }, 100);

  window.addEventListener("message", ({data}) => {
     if(data === "received") clearInterval(ping);
  });
}
```

On the loaded page:

```
 window.addEventListener("message", ({data}) => {
   window.postMessage("received","*");
   //Do whatever with data
});
```