# How to pass JSON data to another window using window.open

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to pass this object in the Javascript Window.open() parameters but so far i havent found anything helpful
{
name:"xxx",
age:21,
country:"xxx"
}

im a beginner in this so i havent really tried anything else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass object data to a window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662164/how-to-pass-object-data-to-a-window-open)

Comment: There are different options. You might also wanna check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and read about [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). But the linked thread is just one part of the story but you need to get the parameters into the URL in one tab and retrieve them on the other (the latter is described in the thread).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.